# XMLHttpRequest: Junk after document element

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to read an xml file which is sent by a server to a web client (browser).

My javascript is from w3School:

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename){
    var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{ // code for IE5 and IE6
      xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

It stops on line "xhttp.send();" with error "junk after document element" on line 15 of this xml file (on the second `<registro>` tag):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<registro>
    <log>
        <luogo>Centrale</luogo>
        <azione>Carico</azione>
        <operatore>STEFANO-STELLA-8934</operatore>
        <stocks>
            <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Minus(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Minus(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="20">Sneaker-Plus(40)</stock>
        </stocks>
        <data>010414</data>
    </log>
</registro>
<registro>
    <log>
        <luogo>Centrale</luogo>
        <azione>Carico</azione>
        <operatore>STEFANO-STELLA-8934</operatore>
        <stocks>
            <stock quantità="4">Conserve-Classic-Green(39)</stock>
            <stock quantità="6">Conserve-Classic-Green(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Conserve-Classic-Green(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="4">Conserve-Classic-Green(42)</stock>
            <stock quantità="4">Conserve-Classic-Green(43)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="16">Sneaker-Country(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="24">Sneaker-Country(42)</stock>
            <stock quantità="16">Sneaker-Country(43)</stock>
            <stock quantità="16">Sneaker-Country(44)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(45)</stock>
            <stock quantità="3">Sneaker-Country(46)</stock>
            <stock quantità="4">Sneaker-Plus(38)</stock>
            <stock quantità="6">Sneaker-Plus(39)</stock>
            <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Plus(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Plus(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Plus(42)</stock>
            <stock quantità="20">Sneaker-Plus(43)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(44)</stock>
        </stocks>
        <data>300314</data>
    </log>
    <log>
        <luogo>Novara01</luogo>
        <azione>Sarico</azione>
        <operatore>STEFANO-STELLA-8934</operatore>
        <stocks>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(39)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(42)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(43)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(42)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(43)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(44)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(45)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(46)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(38)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(39)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Plus(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Plus(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Plus(42)</stock>
            <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Plus(43)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(44)</stock>
        </stocks>
        <data>300314</data>
    </log>
</registro>
<registro>
    <log>
        <luogo>Torino01</luogo>
        <azione>Scarico</azione>
        <operatore>STEFANO-STELLA-8934</operatore>
        <stocks>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(39)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(42)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(43)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(42)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(43)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(44)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(45)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(46)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(38)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(39)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(40)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(41)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(42)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(43)</stock>
            <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(44)</stock>
        </stocks>
        <data>310314</data>
    </log>
</registro>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is invalid, as it has more than 1 root node

Answer (score 1):

Please validate the xml.[xml validate](http://validator.w3.org/check) you don't need `<registro>` tags in between

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<registro>
<log>
    <luogo>Centrale</luogo>
    <azione>Carico</azione>
    <operatore>STEFANO-STELLA-8934</operatore>
    <stocks>
        <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Minus(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Minus(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="20">Sneaker-Plus(40)</stock>
    </stocks>
    <data>010414</data>
</log>

<log>
    <luogo>Centrale</luogo>
    <azione>Carico</azione>
    <operatore>STEFANO-STELLA-8934</operatore>
    <stocks>
        <stock quantità="4">Conserve-Classic-Green(39)</stock>
        <stock quantità="6">Conserve-Classic-Green(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Conserve-Classic-Green(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="4">Conserve-Classic-Green(42)</stock>
        <stock quantità="4">Conserve-Classic-Green(43)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="16">Sneaker-Country(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="24">Sneaker-Country(42)</stock>
        <stock quantità="16">Sneaker-Country(43)</stock>
        <stock quantità="16">Sneaker-Country(44)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(45)</stock>
        <stock quantità="3">Sneaker-Country(46)</stock>
        <stock quantità="4">Sneaker-Plus(38)</stock>
        <stock quantità="6">Sneaker-Plus(39)</stock>
        <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Plus(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Plus(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="30">Sneaker-Plus(42)</stock>
        <stock quantità="20">Sneaker-Plus(43)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(44)</stock>
    </stocks>
    <data>300314</data>
</log>
<log>
    <luogo>Novara01</luogo>
    <azione>Sarico</azione>
    <operatore>STEFANO-STELLA-8934</operatore>
    <stocks>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(39)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(42)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(43)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(42)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(43)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(44)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Country(45)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(46)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(38)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(39)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Plus(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Plus(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Plus(42)</stock>
        <stock quantità="8">Sneaker-Plus(43)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(44)</stock>
    </stocks>
    <data>300314</data>
</log>

<log>
    <luogo>Torino01</luogo>
    <azione>Scarico</azione>
    <operatore>STEFANO-STELLA-8934</operatore>
    <stocks>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(39)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(42)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Conserve-Classic-Green(43)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(42)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(43)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(44)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(45)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Country(46)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(38)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(39)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(40)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(41)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(42)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(43)</stock>
        <stock quantità="2">Sneaker-Plus(44)</stock>
    </stocks>
    <data>310314</data>
  </log>
</registro>
```

Comment: it was so simple! so, I didn't understand xml!